# How to recive data from a Flightcell DZMX via Iridium SBD

Tags: node.js, iridium

I have a Flightcell DZMX configured to send data to a ip and port via iridium SBD, where i have a server with a simple code running that recive any request and display on the screen:

```
 var net = require('net');
    
    var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
        socket.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log(data.toString());  
        })
    });

server.listen(8080, 'my-server-ip-adress');
console.log('Server listening on port 8080');
```

But no message is recived from the DZMX. Is iridium SBD not in TCP protocol or is my DZMX misconfigured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is inded TCP/IP.
You need to configure your equipament IMEI, IP and port in: https://spnetpro.iridium.com

Everything working fine now.